# Listview delete items when clicked javafx

Tags: listview, javafx

I have a listview like this

```
List<SellAbleItems> table1 = Main.readFromTable1();
ListView<SellAbleItems> listOfItems = new ListView<>();
listOfItems.getItems().addAll(table1);
```

This is good because it goes through my table1 items. The list contains of a name and price. And my question goes on how to delete items with a mouse click on a item and then hit a button that say delete? The problem I see, is that I don't know how many items are available, it depends of how many items the user adds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the selected item:

```
int index = listOfItems.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

if (index >= 0) {
    listOfItems.getItems().remove(index);
}
```

Comment: @PeterHoldensgaard Works for me for removing the selected item. Item selection is done as result of a click on the cell. If it's not working for you you're either using it wrong or you your question isn't clear about what "deleting" means...

Comment: I works for me now. Thank you for your help, the code works. I just needed to put it inside my button. Thank you!!